# Jenkins upgrade issue

Tags: jenkins

```
    # systemctl status jenkins

    jenkins.service - LSB: Jenkins continuous build server
    Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/jenkins)
    Active: active (exited) since Tue 2016-11-15 17:12:33 JST; 3min 58s ago
```

I am upgrading jenkins from 1.6 to 2.x but after replacing war file I can not start jenkins that can be seen above.

Comment: /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log?

Comment: I had fixed it. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to download the 1.6 and run it to validate all remain the same and still workable. Probably you have some plugins that not supported (or should be upgraded to be supported) in versions 2+.